# SQL to select rows with certain condition based on status and count

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

```
ID  Foreign_ID  Number   Status_Id
1   101         xyz11    3
2   101         xyz22    3
3   201         xyz33    3
4   201         xyz44    1
5   201         xyz55    7
6   301         xyz66    1
7   301         xyz77    7
8   301         xyz88    7
```

Status_Id, 3 refers to active, 1 refers cancelled, 7 refers to revoked
I want to select the rows that have only status_id 1 or 7 and should not have any active rows. The query should only return rows with 301 (Foreign_ID).

Comment: oracle11g & sql-server-2012 ?

Comment: In general, you will get a better response to your questions if you make an attempt at the first. Have you written any SQL in response to your requirement?

Comment: it is for sql-server 2012. but in general it is to write a sql query. I did try with having clause like this
select * from table having count(Foreign_ID) > 1 and status_Id in (1, 7).... but getting lost..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Select *
From Yourtablename
Where Status_Id in (1, 7)
AND Foreign_ID = 301;
```

Comment: i wanted a generic query that fetches all rows with the conditions

Comment: @Programmer what do you mean by generic query with all rows conditions? Can you specify what columns you want in your output and what exact condition are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` :

```
select * 
from table t
where not exists (
    select 1 from table where Foreign_ID = t.Foreign_ID and Status_Id = 3
);
```

This is called correlated `subquery` where `subquery` is depended on outer query, if the outer query table has 3 rows then `subquery` will execute 3 times.

In your case, the subquery has filter with `status_id = 3` which means it will select only the rows where  status_id = 3 and so forth the outer query has `NOT EXISTS` filter which means it will select the rows where  `status_id <> 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that maybe I haven't fully understand your requirement,
 but this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Status_Id=1 OR Status_Id=7) AND Foreign_ID=301
```

Comment: i gave an example. I want a generic query to fetch all the rows from the table that have only 1, 7 status and not 3 for foreign id . In the example 101 and 201 rows should not be fetched

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant still post a comment.

Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to query `status_id` 1 or 7 then at the end you said you only want to get `foreign_id` 301?

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE WHERE Foreign_ID = 301
```

This will display rows having `Foreign_ID = 301`

If you want to display only the `Foreign_ID` column with `Status_Id` 1 or 7

```
SELECT Foreign_ID FROM YOURTABLE WHERE Status_Id IN (1, 7)
```

Or your 301 `Foreign_ID` also contains `Status_Id` 1? Sorry I'm lost at the end of your statement, and also your table data.

If not, Aurete's answer will satisfy your condition.